# A problem on Runge theorem in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

let $K_1= \overline {D(2,1/2)}\  \cup \overline {D(-2,1/2)}\  $ and $K_2=\overline {D(2i,1/2)}\ \cup \overline {D(-2i,1/2)}\ .$

Is there a sequence $P_n$ of polynomials such that $Pn \to 1$ uniformaly on $K_1$ and $P_n \to -1$ uniformaly on $K_2$ ??

Comment: Runge's theorem says that under certain conditions, there exists a sequence of polynomials converging ..  What part of the conditions or the conclusion are you having trouble with?

Comment: @RobertIsrael is $K_1$ and $K_2$ simple connected ?

Comment: $K_1 \cup K_2$ is the union of four disjoint disks.  Its complement is connected.